# mapStateToProps passing props as empty object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm trying to add Redux to my React Native application. There is a `Decider` app that should control whether or not the `<Intro />` is shown or `<Content />`.

I've never had any issues with linking redux before and have tried different variations so I must be doing something wrong here. FYI The only reason I have a `<Decider />` component is because `<App />` is the root component and following my understanding you can't have a `Provider` and `connect()` on the same component.

Props is coming through as an empty object. What am I doing wrong?

**App.js**

```
import Intro from './pages/Intro';
import Content from './pages/Content';
const store = createStore(rootReducer)

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Decider /> 
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

class Decider extends Component {
  render() {
    return this.props.showIntro ? <Intro /> : <Content />
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    showIntro: state.showIntro
  }
}

connect(mapStateToProps)(Decider)
```

**./reducers/index.js**

```
[...auth reducer...]

const viewControl = (state = true, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ON_INTRO_COMPLETION:
      return action.payload
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default rootReducer = combineReducers({ auth, viewControl });
```

**./actions/index.js**

```
export const onIntroCompletion = bool => {
    return {
        type: 'ON_INTRO_COMPLETION',
        payload: false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your action returns: `payload: true`, and reducer supplies this as the entire state object (`true` or `false`).

But, when you `connect()` your component, you assign try to pull from `state.showIntro`.

In your reducer, try this:

```
case ON_INTRO_COMPLETION:
  return {showIntro: action.payload};
```

Comment: There are no props for `Decider` so why take them into consideration?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Oh, I see--your *redux* props aren't coming through. Let me revise my answer.

Answer (score 0):

From [redux docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/using-combinereducers)

> combineReducers takes an object full of slice reducer functions, and
>   creates a function that outputs a corresponding state object with the
>   same keys.

As state is immutable the new state is constructed with the keys you specify in `combineReducers`, so if
your reducer doesn't fulfill the schema of your state you will lose properties.

You might want to try something like this:

```
export default rootReducer = combineReducers({ 
    auth, 
    viewControl,
    showIntro: showIntro => showIntro
});
```